# How can I save text folds and folded code block data to .sublime-workspace?

Tags: api, plugins, editor, sublimetext2, folding

Seems like there are no features in Sublime Text 2 that keep code folding between file sessions close\open.

I'd like to write plugin for this, but have a question.

Where should I store fold-data such as which file, or region on the page is folded? My Only idea saves in .sublime-workspace

So, how I can access it and read my properties, attributes, or what meta-data not?

Where else can I store data such as what is required to persist fold regions?

Comment: did you write the plugin by storing data to sublime-workspace?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First of all, There's already a really nice plugin that does that and much more, it's called [BufferScroll](https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll)

> Buffer Scroll is a simple Sublime Text plug-in which remembers and restores the scroll, cursor positions, also the selections, marks, bookmarks, foldings, selected syntax and optionally the color scheme.

Trying to answer your question, I did a quick check on BufferScroll source code and it seems that it store all data in Settings folder inside a Gzip file. on mac it's at `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings/BufferScroll.bin.gz`
it's worth to mention that it's the same folder sublime text uses to store session, auto-save session and license files.

Comment: I've been looking for something that does this forever.  Well, six months at least.  Worked great, thanks!

Comment: Late to the party, looks like Buffer Scroll is now only available for ST3. I'm still on ST2 for a few reasons. Is there another alternative anybody knows of for ST2?

Comment: Thanks!! Been waiting my whole life for this!! Buffer Scroll FTW!

Comment: Any alternative for sublime text 2?

Comment: @vzhen you can try clone it, and checkout to the last commit with ST2 support.

Comment: [See this question for instructions on installing BufferScroll in ST2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21616903/1569064)

Answer (score 5):

update sep 2017, using sublime 3, to make fold persistence after we close document, there is [autofoldcode](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFoldCode) in package control, I just installed and it's working as expected.

Comment: Before you install, make sure you read the known issues. A possible workaround is to never close Sublime or shutdown the computer.