# Can I save collapsed code in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

Have code I can forget about all looking nice:

[image: nice]

However, upon closing the file and reopening it:

[image: messy]

How can I collapse this code I'm not going to edit for years(hopefully!) and keep it hidden indefinitely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the [BufferScroll](https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll) plugin will do what you want.

> Buffer Scroll is a simple Sublime Text plug-in which remembers and
>   restores the scroll, cursor positions, also the selections, marks,
>   bookmarks, foldings, selected syntax and optionally the colour scheme,
>   when you open a file. Will also remember different data depending the
>   position of the file in the application (example file1 in window1 has
>   scroll line 30, file1 in window2 has scroll in line 40)
>
> Also, via preferences, allows to enable syncing of scroll, bookmarks,
>   marks and folds between cloned views, live.

Update:

To install this package on ST2, you have to add the repository to your PackageControl user settings:

```
"repositories":
    [
        "https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll"
    ]
```

Now you should be able to do a standard install from ST2.

Comment: Niice works perfectly! However, I did have to update to Sublime Text 3, as Buffer Scroll is only available to ST3. This is a good site for details on how to update to ST3: http://www.unixmen.com/install-sublime-text-3-ubuntu-13-04-13-10/

Comment: I'm using ST2 and I tried to add the repository to my PackageControl user settings, but it didn't work. Could you give us more details on how to do it? Is there a video that shows the process?